# Deselecting select options with jQuery needs scrolling to actually show

Tags: jquery

I have a somewhat odd problem deselecting options in a select using jQuery.

The code I have now (for selecting all):

```
$select.children().attr('selected', true);
```

This works fine.

For deselecting, I have tried various options:

```
$select.children().attr('selected', false);
$select.children().removeAttr('selected');
$select.find("option").attr('selected', false);
$select.find("option").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.removeAttr("selected");
});
```

etc.. and they all have the same problem (tested in chrome / safari). After I run the deselect code, I have to actually scroll before the options are shown as not selected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Regards,
Morten

Comment: I have inspected the DOM, and the select="selected" is indeed gone, just not showing.

Comment: Can you possibly provide a working example, possibly a jsfiddle?  I am unable to reproduce the problem in chrome.

Comment: I can't actually reproduce it with jsfiddle.. must be something else that messes up my DOM? maybe I should have mentioned that this select is dynamically wrapped in a div.. so I'm already messing a bit with the DOM.. not sure if that somehow can mess things up?

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? I'm experiencing the exact same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
$select.val(null);
```

Should revert the displayed value to be the first non-disabled option in the select.